# Bash: concatenated variables derived from text file using grep gives confused output

Tags: bash, grep, string-concatenation, mv

In my directory, I have a multiple nifti files (e.g., `WIP944_mp2rage-0.75iso_TR5.nii`) from my MRI scanner accompanied by text files (e.g., `WIP944_mp2rage-0.75iso_TR5_info.txt`) containing information on the acquisition parameters (e.g., "Series description: WIP944_mp2rage-0.75iso_TR5_INV1_PHS_ND"). Based on these parameters (e.g., `INV1_PHS_ND`), I need to change the nifti file name, which are echoed in $niftibase. I used `grep` to do this. When echoing all variables individually, it gives me what I want, but when I try to concatenate them into one filename, the variables are mixed together, instead of delimited by a dot.

I tried multiple forms of `sed` to cut away potentially invisible characters and identified the source of the problems: the "INV1_PHS_ND" part of 'series description' gives me troubles, which is the $struct component, potentially due to the fact that this part varies in how many fields are extracted. Sometimes this is 3 (in the case of INV1_PHS_ND), but it can be 2 as well (INV1_ND). When I introduce this variable into the filename, everything goes haywire.

```
for infofile in ${PWD}/*.txt; do

  # General characteristics of subjects (i.e., date of session, group number, and subject number)
  reco=$(grep -A0 "Series description:" ${infofile} | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d '_' -f 1)
  date=$(grep -A0 "Series date:" ${infofile} | cut -c 16-21)
  group=$(grep -A0 "Subject:" ${infofile} | cut -d '^' -f 2 | cut -d '_' -f 1 )
  number=$(grep -A0 "Subject:" ${infofile} | cut -d '^' -f 2 | cut -d '_' -f 2)
  ScanNr=$(grep -A0 "Series number:" ${infofile} | cut -d ' ' -f 3)


  # Change name if reco has structural prefix
  if [[ $reco = *WIP944* ]]; then

    struct=$(grep -A0 "Series description: WIP944" ${infofile} | cut -d '_' -f 4,5,6)
    niftibase=$(basename $infofile _info.txt).nii

    #echo ${subStudy}.struct.${date}.${group}.${protocol}.${paradigm}.nii
    echo ${subStudy}.struct.${struct}.${date}.${group}.${protocol}${number}.${paradigm}.n${ScanNr}.nii

    #mv ${niftibase} ${subStudy}.struct.${struct}.${date}.${group}.${protocol}${number}.${paradigm}.n${ScanNr}.nii

  fi

done
```

This gives me output like this:

```
.niit47.n4lot.Noc002
.niit47.n5lot.Noc002D
.niit47.n6lot.Noc002
.niit47.n8lot.Noc002
.niit47.n9lot.Noc002
.niit47.n10ot.Noc002
.niit47.n11ot.Noc002D
```

for all 7 WIP944 files. However, it needs to be in the direction of this:
`H1.struct.INV2_PHS_ND.190523.Pilot.Noc001.Heat47.n11.nii`, where H1, Noc, and Heat47 are loaded in from a setup file.

EDIT: I tried to use awk in the following way:

```
  reco=$(awk 'FNR==8 {print;exit}' $infofile | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d '_' -f 1)
  date=$(awk 'FNR==2 {print;exit}' $infofile | cut -c 15-21)
  group=$(awk 'FNR==6 {print;exit}' $infofile | cut -d '^' -f 2 | cut -d '_' -f 1 )
  number=$(awk 'FNR==6 {print;exit}' $infofile | cut -d '^' -f 2 | cut -d '_' -f 2)
  ScanNr=$(awk 'FNR==14 {print;exit}' $infofile | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

which again gave me the correct output when echoing the variables individually, but not when I tried to combine them: `.niit47.n11022_PHS_ND`.

I used `echo "$struct" | tr -dc '[:print:]' | od -c` to see if there were hidden characters due to line endings, which resulted in:

```
0000000    I   N   V   2   _   P   H   S   _   N   D
0000013
```

EDIT: This is how the text file looks like:

```
Series UID: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.34.18923.2019052316005066316714852.0.0.0
Study date: 20190523
Study time: 153529.718000
Series date: 20190523
Series time: 160111.750000
Subject: MDC-0153,pilot_003^pilot_003
Subject birth date: 19970226
Series description: WIP944_mp2rage-0.75iso_TR5_INV1_PHS_ND
Image type: ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\P\ND
Manufacturer: SIEMENS
Model name: Investigational_Device_7T
Software version: syngo MR B17
Study id: 1
Series number: 5
Repetition time (ms): 5000
Echo time[1] (ms): 2.51
Inversion time (ms): 900
Flip angle: 7
Number of averages: 1
Slice thickness (mm): 0.75
Slice spacing (mm): 
Image columns: 320
Image rows: 320
Phase encoding direction: ROW
Voxel size x (mm): 0.75
Voxel size y (mm): 0.75
Number of volumes: 1
Number of slices: 240
Number of files: 240
Number of frames: 0
Slice duration (ms) : 0
Orientation: sag
PixelBandwidth: 248
```

I have one of these for each nifti file. subStudy is hardcoded in a setup file, which is loaded in prior to running the for loop. When I echo this, it shows the correct value. I need to change the names of multiple files with a specific prefix, which are stored in $reco.

Comment: Looks like you have Windows line endings (CR LF), causing the text to appear overwritten.

Comment: This looks very much like you should try to learn the basics of Awk.

Comment: While I do agree with learning the basics of Awk (never used it before), my system uses unix LF line endings.

Comment: Because of `*.txt;` you should escape the filename like `"${infofile}"` or `"$infofile"`. And I vote for awk too.

Comment: You remove all non-printable characters with `tr -dc '[:print:]'` to look for non-printable characters in the output... nice one. ;-) Try `echo "$struct" | hexdump -C`.

Comment: bash-3.2$ echo "$struct" | hexdump -C
    00000000  49 4e 56 32 5f 50 48 53  5f 4e 44 0d 0a           |INV2_PHS_ND..|
    0000000d

Comment: Yeah, the `0d` is a DOS carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed in comments, the input files have DOS carriage returns, which are [basically invalid in Unix files.](/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) Also, you should pay attention to [proper quoting.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642)

As a general overhaul, I would recommend replacing the entire Bash script with a simple Awk script, which is both simpler and more idiomatic.

```
for infofile in ./*.txt; do  # no need to use $(PWD)
   # Pre-filter with a simple grep
   grep -q '^Series description: [^ _]*WIP944' "$infofile" && continue
   # Still here? Means we want to rename
   suffix="$(awk -F : '
     BEGIN { split("Series description:Series date:Subject:Series number", f, /:/) }
     { sub(/\r/, ""); } # get rid of pesky DOS carriage return
     NR == 1 { nifbase = FILENAME; sub(/_info\.txt$/, ".nii", nifbase) }
     $1 in f { x[$1] = substring($0, length($1)+2) }
     END {
       split(x["Series description"], t, /_/); struct=t[4] "_" t[5] "_" t[6]
       split(x["Series description"], t, /_/); reco = t[1]
       date=substr(x["Series date"], 16, 5)
       split(x["Subject"], t, /\^/); split(t[2], tt, /_/); group=tt[1]
       number=tt[2]
       ScanNr=x["Series number"]
       ### FIXME: protocol and paradigm are still undefined
       print struct "." date "." group "." protocol number "." paradigm ".n" ScanNr
     }' "$infofile")"
  echo mv "$infofile" "$subStudy.struct.$suffix"
done
```

This probably still requires some tweaking (at least "protocol" and "paradigm" are still undefined). Once it seems to print the correct values, you can remove the `echo` before `mv` and have it actually rename files for you.

(Probably still better test on a copy of your real data files first!)

Comment: I've added the content of a text file in the OP. I have a text file for each scan, in which the variables I want to store in the name are the aspects of the text file that separate the nifti files.

Comment: See update now. I trust you will be able to finish the missing pieces on your own with a little bit of googling.